# Manipulating strings in C with user input

Tags: c, string

I am working on a program for my comp sci classes and the problem asks to take a command from the user and the string that. Then, use either "reverse " to reverse the string that follows or "create " to print the string that follows. The reverse output should keep the words reverse, then print the string that follows in reverse.

```
/* for Reverse command */
else if(strcmp(str,"reverse ") > 0)
{
    reverse(str);
    printf("Reverse of string: %s\n", str);
}
```

The following function is used to reverse the word:

```
void reverse(char *string)
{
    int length, i;
    char *begin, *end, temp;

    length = strlen(string);

    begin = string;
    end = string;

    for (i = 0 ; i < (length - 1) ; i++)
    end++;

    for (i = 0 ; i < length/2 ; i++)
    {
       temp = *end;
       *end = *begin;
       *begin = temp;

     begin++;
     end--;
    }
}
```

The output reverses all the words and prints. Is there a way to break off the reverse part of the string before it is passed to the reverse function?

Comment: Show some output of the code, and what you want to output.

Comment: Give a command: reverse hello world
    Reverse of string: dlrow olleh esrever

Comment: That's what's actually happening or what you expect? Please edit in your question.

Comment: I want the output to be "reverse dlrow olleh"

Comment: Then all you have to do is to read 2 strings instead of 1.The first string will be the command(you don't reverse it), and the second string you will apply the `reverse()`. All this is assuming you read `reverse hello world` in one string.

Comment: I have to use one string and manipulate it to only print the string after the command reverse in reverse. Can I use a loop to print till I get to the string "reverse "?

Comment: Why do you need only 1 string? Doing `scanf("%s %s", &command, &string);` you can write `reverse hello world` and it will initialize `command` -> `reverse` and `string` -> `hello world`

Comment: Or if you really need it in one string then you could increment with a pointer over that string until you finish the `reverse` key word, then reverse what's left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before calling the function `reverse`, use

```
char *ptr=strchr(str,' ');
str=++ptr;
```

To cut off "reverse" from `str`.`string.h` needs to be included to use `strchr`.`strchr` returns a pointer to the first occurrence of the character `' '` in the string `str`, or `NULL` if the character is not
found.`ptr` is incremented once before assigning it to `str` to remove the space from the string.

Comment: I get this error "incompatible types when assigning to type ‘char[200]’ from type ‘char *’"

Comment: My str variable is defined as str[200]

Comment: @nerd4life ,Try `strcpy(str,++ptr);` instead of `str=++ptr;`